# RLMException when calling callback closure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I am still trying to wrap my mind around on how to perform Realm queries with GDC.

I have this code in one of my classes:

```
class func placeNameForChatChannel(chatChannel: String, withCompletion handler: (String?)->())  {

    dispatch_async(realmQueue) {
        var channelEnvPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "channelName = %@", chatChannel)
        var channelEnvs = PSTChannelEnvironment.objectsInRealm(realmdb, withPredicate: channelEnvPredicate)

        if channelEnvs.count > 0 {

            var channelEnvironment = channelEnvs[0] as! PSTChannelEnvironment
            let placeName = channelEnvironment.placeName
            handler(placeName)

        } else {
            handler(nil)
        }

    }
}
```

These two are declared as globals in my `Application Delegate`

```
var realmdb: RLMRealm {
    return RLMRealm.defaultRealm() 
}

var realmQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.realmdb", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

I am getting the now infamous `RLMException, reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread` when the `handler` callback is getting called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you recreate the `RLMRealm` on every `dispatch` to a GCD queue. If, instead of using that `realmdb`, you use `RLMRealm.defaultRealm()`, do things work?

Comment: The `realmdb` is a computed property and creates and returns a new `defaultRealm()` every time, no? I tried explicitly creating a new `Realm` in my method as you suggested but the problem unfortunately persists.

Comment: Can you share the actual stack trace?